# Index/Match formula referencing separate sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a number of sheets that will vary from one use case to another. In this example, let's assume I have 3 sheets called `"Lever 1"`, `"Lever 2"` and `"Lever 3"`. For each one of these there are 3 more sheets titled as follows:
For sheet `"Lever 1"` - `"Lever 1Query1", "Lever 1Query2", "Lever 1Query3"`
For sheet `"Lever 2"` - `"Lever 2Query1", "Lever 2 Query2", "Lever 2Query3"`
For sheet `"Lever 3"` - `"Lever 3Query1", "Lever 3Query2", "Lever 3Query3"`
and so on

I am trying to write a VBA script that will input the following formula in all `"Lever X"` sheets:

`=INDEX('Lever XQuery2'!$C$2:$C$10000,MATCH(1,($F4='Lever XQuery2'!$B$2:$B$10000)*($G4='Lever XQuery2'!$A$2:$A$10000),0))`

So far, I have this VBA code which I'm hoping someone can help me fix:

```
For i = 1 To wBk.Worksheets.Count
Sheets("Lever " & i).Range("I4:I10000").Values = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("'Lever " & i & "Query2'!$C$2:$C$10000"), _
            WorksheetFunction.Match(1, ("$F4"=Range("'Lever " & i & "Query2'!$B2$:$B$10000")) _
            * ("$G4"=Range("'Lever " & i & "Query2'!$A2$:$A$10000")),0)
Next i
```

Comment: What works and what doesn't? Which part specifically do you need help with? I mean I expect that loop to throw an error when it doesn't find a sheet with that number, but is the rest working?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber the loop is returning an error, which is fine. The issue is the VBA code is not populating the formula in any of the sheets. This makes me think there is a problem with the way I coded the Index/Match formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Formulas Using VBA

- This covers only `Query2`. I don't understand the connection to `Query1` and `Query3`. Hopefully, you mean to do something similar using different formulas.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFormulas()
    
    Const lPattern As String = "LEVER *"
    Const lRangeAddress As String = "I4:I10000"
    Const qSuffix As String = "Query2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet ' Each (Possible Lever) Worksheet
    Dim qws As Worksheet ' Query Worksheet
    Dim lwsID As Variant ' Lever Worksheet ID
    Dim lwsName As String ' Lever Worksheet Name
    Dim qwsName As String ' Query Worksheet Name
    
    ' Loop through all worksheets.
    For Each lws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Write the name of the current worksheet to a variable.
        lwsName = lws.Name
        ' Test if current worksheet follows the pattern.
        If UCase(lwsName) Like UCase(lPattern) Then
            ' Attempt (As Variant) to determine the Lever Worksheet ID ('*').
            lwsID = Right(lwsName, Len(lwsName) - Len(lPattern) + 1)
            ' Test if '*' is a number.
            If IsNumeric(lwsID) Then
                ' Determine the Query Worksheet Name.
                qwsName = lwsName & qSuffix
                ' Attempt to create a reference to the Query Worksheet.
                On Error Resume Next
                Set qws = wb.Worksheets(qwsName)
                On Error GoTo 0
                ' Test for existence of Query Worksheet.
                If Not qws Is Nothing Then
                    ' Write formulas to Lever Worksheet.
                    lws.Range(lRangeAddress).Formula = "=INDEX('" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$C$2:$C$10000,MATCH(1,($F4='" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$B$2:$B$10000)*($G4='" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$A$2:$A$10000),0))"
                    Set qws = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```